# Checkbox clicking item under it

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I am programming two drop down menus in a search form. However, I have one which overlays the other when opened. Not a problem, until I click the checkboxes that overlap the other drop down, then it clicks the menu button below the checkbox and not the checkbox itself.

```
<ul>
  <div id="drops"><li><a href="#" onclick="toggle('drop-wrapper');">Categories</a></div> 
    <div id="drop-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select-all-cat" id="select-all-cat" /><label for="cities-label" class="categories-label">Select all</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="products"><label class="categories-label">Products</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="services"><label class="categories-label">Services</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="real_estate" value="real_estate"><label class="categories-label">Real estate</label><br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#drop-wrapper {
margin-top: 10px;
background-color: #000;
left: -30%;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
z-index: 10000;
width: 180px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The problem occurs when I click the "Products" checkbox, it click the menu button behind it.

Comment: Can you add a sample or what you already tried ?

Comment: Why not add details instead of suggesting to add?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to set the positon of the control you are tring to operate on to `relative` and change `z-index` of it to a larget number to make sure it is positioned above the other control.

More about [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

The z-index property specifies the z-order of an element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

> For a **positioned** box, the z-index property specifies:
>
> - The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> - Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

P.S. If this does not solve your issue, please provide a sample code.

Comment: I understand the z-index function, but it still doesn't work, so it's something else I'm doing wrong. I have now posted code.